# Sorting Vim lines by perl sort (because builtin sort does not process UTF8 in Windows 7 properly)

Tags: perl, sorting, vim, utf-8, text-editor

I have to edit a large text file with over 600000 Russian lowercased words in UTF8 format.

Each word is located on a separate line and the file has been successfully sorted by a Perl script (using its `sort` function):

[image]

The character range is `0x0430 - 0x044F` (please see [the Unicode range chart](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0400.pdf)).

**My problem is:** I must keep the file sorted during my editing of it and its parts, but when I use the Vim's builtin (or is it Windows) `%!sort` then the Russian letters are sorted by their numeric codes and not alphabetically.

**And my question is:** I have `perl` in the `%path%` - how could I please use it to sort the file I'm editing in the Vim editor (whole and parts of it)?

Comment: `:%s!sort` isn't sort, it's a substitute that removes 'sort' on each line. `:%!sort` is Windows SORT.EXE and `:%sort` is vim sort.

Comment: +1 Thanks, that was a typo. And you have answered my question: `:%sort` works well for me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be sure to look at

```
:help perldo
```

to see whether perl support is built right in for your copy of Vim.

Alternatively,

```
 %!perl -e 'print foreach sort (<>)'
```

should get you started using external Perl

PS. Also look at `help :sort` as I'm not quite sure you have been using Vim sort until now

**Update** I just tried with the 1000 words from http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/User:Dart_evader/Russian_1-1000 and using the 'external' perl oneliner like above had ***exactly*** the same result as just doing (on linux)

```
:%sort
```

Comment: Thanks, but `perldo` seems to apply to the current line only (in `$_`) - how to sort the file by using it?

Comment: @AlexanderFarber well, I don't know :) After the update, it should not really be relevant anyways?

Comment: Yes, `:%sort` works well (I was using `:%!sort` before), thanks!